# How to use querydsl to do a operation in a object with a list?

Tags: java, list, object, querydsl

I have a *path* object in java created by querydsl.

This is the result of toString method: **lote.edificacoes.id**

**lote** is the object

**edificacoes** is the list inside the object

**id** is the attribute that i'd like to do the operation

When i use *path.gt(100)* for example, i'm getting the following error: **illegal attempt to dereference collection**

It's not possible do a join cause i just have the *path* object because this object is created by a reflection.

This a example from my code

**Lote class**

```
@Entity
public class Lote {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "lote", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private List<Edificacao> edificacoes;
   //getter and setter
}
```

> path.gt(100);

I expected the output of the list of results, a list of **Lote**

Comment: well, but "gt" is short for "greater than". Of course that does not pan out

Comment: your query looks like "query.where(Qlote.lote.edificacoes.any().id.gt(100));" ?

Comment: I found this [information](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-issues/2007-July/006157.html). Apparently a path with a collection/list is not supported. Does this information confer?

Comment: @imperezivan, no, it isn't like.

Comment: @Nikolas, i think that isn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the documentation this is not possible.

http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-issues/2007-July/006157.html